# How to change the text of navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem for iPhone

Tags: iphone

How do I change the text value `navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem`?

In view A I did `self.title=@"hi"`

So when I go to B my back button has the text **@"hi"**. now I want to change it to **back**

How do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"blah blah blah" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:nil action:nil];
self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backButton;
[backButton release];
```

you can use this in view A and enter any text you want

Comment: awesome thanks a lot i was trying same thing but in View B . never thought of A  :(  you saved me :-)